# Mockito: verify any() parameter is the same

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I would like to do something like:

```
MyEnum myEnum = any();  // This is not allowed throws InvalidUseOfMatchersException
MyClassUtils.method(myClass, myEnum);

// Verify MyClassUtils.method(MyEnum) calls myClass.method(MyEnum)
verify(myClass).method(myEnum);
```

The idea is that I don't care which enum is passed into `MyClassUtils#method(MyEnum)`, as long as it's the same enum that gets passed into `MyClass#method(MyEnum)`.

**QUESTION:** Is there a Mockito way for me to test this without having to specify a specific enum?

---

I know I could just use:

```
MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum.FIRST;
```

But, this seems misleading because it suggests that I'm testing something specific to `MyEnum.FIRST`.

Comment: *"But, is there a Mockito way for me to test this without having to specify a specific enum?"* For what? Where do you see any advantage?

Comment: @Tom I think It's the same reason you would use any(), to better express the intent of the test.

Comment: I don't use `any` to "tell" that I don't care about something (at least mostly), I used it to tell, that I don't know a certain argument, so I would like accept everything (and yes, this implies that I also don't care, since I don't use an ArgumentCatcher). In this case, I would still use a specific Enum and give it a prober name to tell, that this is just a randomly selected one. If you still want to use a real random one, then you could use `MyEnum w = MyEnum.values()[new Random().nextInt(MyEnum.values().length)];`, but this looks very ugly.

Comment: Btw: since Mockito works with inheritance, I don't assume that it can mock an enum.

Comment: @Tom, I don't need to mock it. I'm looking for something similar to any(), which works fine with Enum but not in the way I want to use it. If nothing exists, then it's not a big deal; however I wanted to make sure first.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't what `any()` is for. Basically, if you want a value for the Enum to be used during the test, you're going to have to pick one.

Comment: Mockito does not do magic. What do you expect? That it tests it for all enum values? Write a parameterized test. That it tests it for one random enum value? Determine that random value yourself. That it tests it for a mocked enum value? Enums are sort-of final, so no luck there. What you are asking doesn't make much sense - either you want to test if it works with one enum value (because then it will work for all) or you want to test it with all enum values - in both cases, do so. If you need the readability, write a `getRandomEnumValue()` method.

Comment: Just for the sake of the argument and if you really need it, you should be able to mock enums using [powermock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) with a combination of `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` & `@PrepareForTest(MyEnum.class)` & `PowerMockito.mock(MyEnum.class);`

Comment: @Morfic thanks. However for me, I think the answer is to just test a specific Enum. It's not something that I needed for testing, just something I wanted to semantically convey my intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking about your test backwards: the characteristic of your `MyClassUtils` object that you're trying to verify is: "no matter what instance of `MyEnum` is passed into it, it always calls `myObject.method` with that same instance".

Loosely translated, this is:

```
∀ x: x ← MyEnum

   where o ← MyClass

   MyClassUtils.method(o, x) ⇒ o.method(x)
```

(Excuse my terrible math editing skills here.)

To test this characteristic exhaustively, you need to verify it for every possible value of `MyEnum`. You can easily do this by using a `for` loop, or you could use something like the JUnit `Parameterized` runner.

However, an exhaustive test is probably not warranted here. Instead, simply select a representative subset which should exercise all expected behaviors of your system under test. It's possible that testing with any arbitrarily chosen element of `MyEnum` is sufficient, and if so there is no harm in doing just that.

One common way to do that is to select a "sample" value and store it in a constant in your test class. By being explicit, debugging is easier: if it later turns out that your representative value was not representative after all, it should be easier to debug if you have the value right there.

TL;DR: a single arbitrarily chosen value should be fine for your test. If it isn't, the solution is to be more exhaustive in your testing, not to be more arbitrary.